# Mysql return total capacity for each VM in stats table

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have a table which contains rows of data for 215 VMs. Each row has the following information VM name, datestamp, disk, capacity, throughput, iops, etc.

each VM will have one or more disks, which means for each datestamp there may be more than one row of data for each vm per datestamp.

[image: raw stats table]

What I need are results with the total disk capacity per VM. It doesn't matter which datestamp I get the data from as it generally stays the same for each datestamp. However not all VM's exist during each datestamp.

So here is what I have tried.

Query attempt 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `VM`, SUM(CapacityGB) as cap FROM stats Group By `VM`
```

The issue here is that I get results for each VM, but instead of the sum of capacity for a single datestamp, it sums ALL datestamps for that VM, which means the capacity is WAY to high

[image: results with wrong capacity]

Query attempt 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `VM`,`datestamp`, SUM(CapacityGB) as cap FROM stats Group By `VM`,`datestamp`
```

this query gives me the proper capacity results, but I get a row for each datestamp for each VM (i have 215 vms and it returns 394701 rows because I have about 2 weeks worth of stats on 10 minute intervals)

[image: too many rows per vm in these results]

So what I would like is a hybrid, 1 row of results per VM. any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just wrap your second query up as a subquery and select the `MAX` value of `cap` (which should be the same as any of the others), grouping by `VM`:

```
SELECT VM, MAX(cap)
FROM (SELECT `VM`,`datestamp`, SUM(CapacityGB) as cap 
      FROM stats 
      GROUP BY `VM`,`datestamp`) s
GROUP BY VM
```

Comment: this works great. And it's super quick! I appreciate it Nick